# File ended while scanning use of \@writefile. <inserted text> \par l.53 \begin{document}

Tags: floats

I just got this error with my Latex code :

```
Runaway argument?
{\contentsline {section}{\numberline {4.3}Température d'équilibre d\ETC
./TM écrit .tex:53 : File ended while scanning use of \@writefile.
<inserted text>
               \par
l.53 \begin{document}

?
```

and my code is this :

```
\documentclass[12pt, letterpaper, twoside, openany]{extbook}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\usepackage[font=scriptsize, labelfont=bf]{caption}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{float}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathmorphing} 
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix} 
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage[multiple]{footmisc}
\usepackage[bindingoffset=14mm]{geometry}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\newtagform{fn}{(}{)\footnotemark}
\graphicspath{ {/Users/coco/Desktop/School/TM/Worksheet - graph_exc.pdf} {/Users/coco/Desktop/School/TM/Worksheet - graph_obl.pdf}{/Users/coco/Desktop/School/TM/Worksheet - graph_pre.pdf}}
\AddThinSpaceBeforeFootnotes
\FrenchFootnotes
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{2061}{}

\definecolor{blue}{RGB}{0,0,255}

\interfootnotelinepenalty=10000

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{5}

\usepackage{afterpage}
\newcommand\pagevide{
\null
\thispagestyle{empty}
\addtocounter{page}{0}
\newpage
}


\setlength{\headheight}{14.5pt}

\titleformat{\chapter}[frame]
{\LARGE}
{\filright\rmfamily\bfseries\LARGE\enspace\thechapter\enspace}
{18pt}
{\rmfamily\LARGE\bfseries\filcenter}

\begin{document}

\chapter{TEMPÉRATURE D'ÉQUILIBRE DE LA TERRE} 

\section{Introduction}

\section{Variations de la constante solaire}

La constante solaire varie selon des cycles de 11 ans, cette variation est dû notamment aux fluctuations du nombres de taches solaires et à l’activité solaire. C’est un paramètre important car de légères oscillations de l’irradiance solaire peuvent créer d’importants changement de notre climat. Malgré le fait que cette affirmation est controversée, un quasi-consensus s’accorde à dire que ces variations existent belle et bien mais uniquement d’approximativement 0,1\%, soit une variation de 0,5 $W/m^2$ à 5 $W/m^2$. Voici un graphique permettant de mieux visualiser ces variations :

\begin{figure}[H]
\centering
\hspace*{-0.5cm}\includegraphics[width=14cm]{solar_cycle_variations.pdf}
\caption[Variations de la constante solaire annuel (courbe rouge) et journalière (courbe jaune), durant la période 1975-2005, mise en relation avec le nombre de taches solaire (courbe bleue), le nombre d’éruptions solaires (courbe verte) et le flux de la radio sur une longueur d’onde de 10.7 cm (courbe violette)]{Variations de la constante solaire annuel (courbe rouge) et journalière (courbe jaune), durant la période 1975-2005, mise en relation avec le nombre de taches solaire (courbe bleue), le nombre d’éruptions solaires (courbe verte) et le flux de la radio sur une longueur d’onde de 10.7 cm (courbe violette).\footnotemark}
\end{figure}
\footnotetext{Source image : R.A. Rohde, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Solar-cycle-data.png\#file}

\end{document}
```

My document worked perfectly before i put the last part (the figure and the text), but when i erase this part the error is still there.

Can somebody help me ? Thank You !!

Comment: Delete your temporary files (`.aux`, `.lof`, etc.).

Comment: Provide a minimal working example, i.e., a minimal example which one can work with, i.e., a minimal example which lets one reproduce the error so that one can trace it. A minimal example also contains those components of the preamble (documentclass, packages) that are needed for reproducing the error. Info about version of LaTeX-kernel, documentclass and packages is useful as well and can be obtained from the .log-file when in the preamble doing `\listfiles`.

Comment: The error-message displayed indicates that the error-message probably is produced while processing a `\@writefile`-entry of the .aux-file for creating an entry for the .toc-file, holding data of the table of contents, coming from `\chapter{TEMPÉRATURE D'ÉQUILIBRE DE LA TERRE} `. But one cannot do error-tracing without exact info about documentclass and packages involved in producing the error.

Answer (score 1):

I cannot reproduce your error-message.

When renaming one of my .pdf-files to `solar_cycle_variations.pdf` and prepending `\listfiles` to your code and adding `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` and commenting out `\pagestyle{fancy}` so that the code is

```latex
\listfiles
\documentclass[12pt, letterpaper, twoside, openany]{extbook}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{graphicx}
%\pagestyle{fancy}
\usepackage[font=scriptsize, labelfont=bf]{caption}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{float}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathmorphing} 
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix} 
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage[multiple]{footmisc}
\usepackage[bindingoffset=14mm]{geometry}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\newtagform{fn}{(}{)\footnotemark}
\graphicspath{ {/Users/coco/Desktop/School/TM/Worksheet - graph_exc.pdf} {/Users/coco/Desktop/School/TM/Worksheet - graph_obl.pdf}{/Users/coco/Desktop/School/TM/Worksheet - graph_pre.pdf}}
\AddThinSpaceBeforeFootnotes
\FrenchFootnotes
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{2061}{}

\definecolor{blue}{RGB}{0,0,255}

\interfootnotelinepenalty=10000

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{5}

\usepackage{afterpage}
\newcommand\pagevide{
\null
\thispagestyle{empty}
\addtocounter{page}{0}
\newpage
}


\setlength{\headheight}{14.5pt}

\titleformat{\chapter}[frame]
{\LARGE}
{\filright\rmfamily\bfseries\LARGE\enspace\thechapter\enspace}
{18pt}
{\rmfamily\LARGE\bfseries\filcenter}

\begin{document}

\chapter{TEMPÉRATURE D'ÉQUILIBRE DE LA TERRE} 

\section{Introduction}

\section{Variations de la constante solaire}

La constante solaire varie selon des cycles de 11 ans, cette variation est dû notamment aux fluctuations du nombres de taches solaires et à l’activité solaire. C’est un paramètre important car de légères oscillations de l’irradiance solaire peuvent créer d’importants changement de notre climat. Malgré le fait que cette affirmation est controversée, un quasi-consensus s’accorde à dire que ces variations existent belle et bien mais uniquement d’approximativement 0,1\%, soit une variation de 0,5 $W/m^2$ à 5 $W/m^2$. Voici un graphique permettant de mieux visualiser ces variations :

\begin{figure}[H]
\centering
\hspace*{-0.5cm}\includegraphics[width=14cm]{solar_cycle_variations.pdf}
\caption[Variations de la constante solaire annuel (courbe rouge) et journalière (courbe jaune), durant la période 1975-2005, mise en relation avec le nombre de taches solaire (courbe bleue), le nombre d’éruptions solaires (courbe verte) et le flux de la radio sur une longueur d’onde de 10.7 cm (courbe violette)]{Variations de la constante solaire annuel (courbe rouge) et journalière (courbe jaune), durant la période 1975-2005, mise en relation avec le nombre de taches solaire (courbe bleue), le nombre d’éruptions solaires (courbe verte) et le flux de la radio sur une longueur d’onde de 10.7 cm (courbe violette).\footnotemark}
\end{figure}
\footnotetext{Source image : R.A. Rohde, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Solar-cycle-data.png\#file}

\end{document}
```

I get a nice .pdf-file and a  warning about an underfull `\hbox` and a warning about an underfull `\vbox`. That's all:

[image]

[image]

Packages in use on my system are:

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.21 (TeX Live 2020) (preloaded format=pdflatex 2021.2.27)  3 OCT 2021 14:18
entering extended mode
 restricted \write18 enabled.
 %&-line parsing enabled.
**test.tex
(./test.tex
LaTeX2e <2020-10-01> patch level 4
L3 programming layer <2021-02-18>
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/extsizes/extbook.cls
Document Class: extbook 1999/01/07 v1.4a NON-Standard LaTeX document class
[...]
 *File List*
 extbook.cls    1999/01/07 v1.4a NON-Standard LaTeX document class
    bk12.clo    2020/04/10 v1.4m Standard LaTeX file (size option)
 exscale.sty    2018/09/24 v2.1i Standard LaTeX package exscale
inputenc.sty    2020/08/01 v1.3d Input encoding file
 fontenc.sty
fancyhdr.sty    2021/01/28 v4.0.1 Extensive control of page headers and footers

graphicx.sty    2020/09/09 v1.2b Enhanced LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)
  keyval.sty    2014/10/28 v1.15 key=value parser (DPC)
graphics.sty    2020/08/30 v1.4c Standard LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)
    trig.sty    2016/01/03 v1.10 sin cos tan (DPC)
graphics.cfg    2016/06/04 v1.11 sample graphics configuration
  pdftex.def    2020/10/05 v1.2a Graphics/color driver for pdftex
 caption.sty    2020/10/26 v3.5g Customizing captions (AR)
caption3.sty    2020/10/21 v2.2e caption3 kernel (AR)
titlesec.sty    2019/10/16 v2.13 Sectioning titles
 amsmath.sty    2020/09/23 v2.17i AMS math features
 amstext.sty    2000/06/29 v2.01 AMS text
  amsgen.sty    1999/11/30 v2.0 generic functions
  amsbsy.sty    1999/11/29 v1.2d Bold Symbols
  amsopn.sty    2016/03/08 v2.02 operator names
mathtools.sty    2020/03/24 v1.24 mathematical typesetting tools
    calc.sty    2017/05/25 v4.3 Infix arithmetic (KKT,FJ)
 mhsetup.sty    2017/03/31 v1.3 programming setup (MH)
tabularx.sty    2020/01/15 v2.11c `tabularx' package (DPC)
   array.sty    2020/10/01 v2.5c Tabular extension package (FMi)
   float.sty    2001/11/08 v1.3d Float enhancements (AL)
    tikz.sty    2020/12/27 v3.1.8b (3.1.8b)
     pgf.sty    2020/12/27 v3.1.8b (3.1.8b)
  pgfrcs.sty    2020/12/27 v3.1.8b (3.1.8b)
pgfrcs.code.tex
 pgfcore.sty    2020/12/27 v3.1.8b (3.1.8b)
  pgfsys.sty    2020/12/27 v3.1.8b (3.1.8b)
pgfsys.code.tex
pgfsyssoftpath.code.tex    2020/12/27 v3.1.8b (3.1.8b)
pgfsysprotocol.code.tex    2020/12/27 v3.1.8b (3.1.8b)
  xcolor.sty    2016/05/11 v2.12 LaTeX color extensions (UK)
   color.cfg    2016/01/02 v1.6 sample color configuration
pgfcore.code.tex
pgfcomp-version-0-65.sty    2020/12/27 v3.1.8b (3.1.8b)
pgfcomp-version-1-18.sty    2020/12/27 v3.1.8b (3.1.8b)
  pgffor.sty    2020/12/27 v3.1.8b (3.1.8b)
 pgfkeys.sty    
pgfkeys.code.tex
 pgfmath.sty    
pgfmath.code.tex
pgffor.code.tex
tikz.code.tex
textcomp.sty    2020/02/02 v2.0n Standard LaTeX package
footmisc.sty    2011/06/06 v5.5b a miscellany of footnote facilities
geometry.sty    2020/01/02 v5.9 Page Geometry
  ifvtex.sty    2019/10/25 v1.7 ifvtex legacy package. Use iftex instead.
   iftex.sty    2020/03/06 v1.0d TeX engine tests
   babel.sty    2021/02/22 3.54 The Babel package
  french.ldf    2020/10/10 v3.5l French support from the babel system
scalefnt.sty    
afterpage.sty    2014/10/28 v1.08 After-Page Package (DPC)
l3backend-pdftex.def    2021-02-18 L3 backend support: PDF output (pdfTeX)
supp-pdf.mkii
epstopdf-base.sty    2020-01-24 v2.11 Base part for package epstopdf
epstopdf-sys.cfg    2010/07/13 v1.3 Configuration of (r)epstopdf for TeX Live
solar_cycle_variations.pdf    Graphic file (type pdf)
 ***********
```

**The documentclass** (`extbook.cls` ) **and some of the packages** (e.g., `amstext.sty`, `amsgen.sty`, `amsbsy.sty`, `amsopn.sty`, `footmisc.sty`) **seem to be rather old and probably need maintenance for adjusting to the latest changes in the LaTeX-kernel and other packages.**

Without `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` I additionally get warnings about fontshapes being missing and about the need of loading fontenc with T1-encoding when using the French language.

With `\pagestyle{fancy}` the page-header looks weird:

[image]

But nowhere I get errors related to creating the .toc-file like

```
Runaway argument?
{\contentsline {section}{\numberline {4.3}Température d'équilibre d\ETC
./TM écrit .tex:53 : File ended while scanning use of \@writefile.
<inserted text>
```

**Probably something was wrong during a prior compilation and in the meantime was fixed so that you need to delete all auxiliary files (.aux, .toc, etc) before compiling anew.**

Probably the colons `:` within the url of your `\footnotetext` should be preceded by `\string`, i.e.,

```latex
\footnotetext{Source image : R.A. Rohde, https\string://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File\string:Solar-cycle-data.png\#file}
```

, yielding

[image]

instead of

```latex
\footnotetext{Source image : R.A. Rohde, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Solar-cycle-data.png\#file}
```

, yielding

[image]

.

Perhaps you can use the command `\url` from the package hyperref or the package url for turning the url into a clickable hyperlink where you can reach the source-image.